# Check javascript object property type

Tags: javascript, performance

I was wondering if there is a way to define an object property type in javascript. What I mean is, if I have an object and I want to make sure the property `a` is a string, is there a way to do this ?

So far I have found a solution using getters and setters:

```
const anObject = {

    "value": "a value", 

    get a () {
        return this.value 
    }, 

    set a (val) {
        if (typeof(val) == "string") {
            this.value = val
        } else {
            throw "Invalid type!"
        }
    }

}
```

Is this efficient? is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

P.S. I am aware that js is a non typed language, so I do not expect any magical answer, but maybe people have come up with some smart workarounds.

Comment: I think this is the only proper way. And this will not be that expensive

Comment: Just a pointer though, instad of using `this.value = `, use a local private variable like `value = `. This will ensure, `value` can be overridden from setter and adding `obj.value = something`, will not break your code.

Comment: Ah, good thinking. Let me update that.

Comment: please do not update question based on suggestions in comments or answer. If you want, you can add a edit section mentioning it. Updating question essentially makes the suggestion void.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a value a property of the object and use  module reveakl patter to incapsulate it. Becouse now nothing can stop me from assinging a number or somth else to your value

```
function value () {
  let value = "";
  return {
    get () {
      return value
    },
    set (val) {
      if (typeof val !== 'string') {
        return 
      }
      value = val
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am aware of how factory functions work, but I did not include it here to not lose focus on what I am trying to achieve. My problem is really type checking, and not variable privacy.

Comment: Question: what does this mean in get or set? What will this.value update?